# while connecting to SAP Quality System, throw an Connection Exception exception

Tags: c#, sap-basis

While connecting with SAP Quality System its Gives an Exception is ConnectionException was caught. details below:

> Details: ErrorCode=RFC_OK. ErrorGroup=RFC_ERROR_COMMUNICATION. SapErrorMessage=SAP_CMINIT3 : rc=20 > Connect to SAP gateway failed
>
> Connect_PM  GWHOST=**IPAddress**, GWSERV=sapgw02, SYSNR=02
>
> LOCATION    CPIC (TCP/IP) on local host with Unicode
>
> ERROR       partner **'IP-Address'** not reached

And the connection string in App.Config is :

```
value="sap://CLIENT=643;SYSTEM ID=QSG;LANG=;@A/**IPAddress**/01" 
value="sap://CLIENT=643;SYSTEM ID=QSG;LANG=;@A/**IPAddress**/02" 

key="userid" value="UserName" 
key="password" value="Password"
```

Program Code

```
SAPBinding binding = new SAPBinding();
//SAPBinding binding1 = Skelta.SAPConnector.SAPAdapter.SAPConnection.binding;

binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
binding.EnableBusinessObjects = true;
binding.EnableSafeTyping = true;

EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(SAPConnectionString);
ChannelFactory<IRequestChannel> factory = new ChannelFactory<IRequestChannel>(binding, address);

// add credentials
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = SAPUserName;
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = SAPPassword;

// Open client
factory.Open(TimeSpan.MaxValue);

//get a channel from the factory
irc = factory.CreateChannel();
//open the channel
try
{
    irc.Open(TimeSpan.MaxValue);
}
```

Please help me

Comment: Ya @PatrickHofman it is pinging.

Comment: i will add the program part also in question.

Comment: Verify the connection settings - they are obviously incorrect, and nobody here will be able to tell you the correct settings.

Comment: With this code, i'm able to connect SAP Production System @vwegert

Comment: thanks @vwegert your suggestion is helped in solving my error.Thanks a lot.